# Hazelcast class definition on server for serialization

Tags: java, web-deployment, hazelcast

Can someone please point me to decent non-mickymouse example of hazelcast client server deployment?

If I have a java web project with client requesting cache server to cache an object ABCD; does the server need to have class file for ABCD? if yes, what is the deployment mechanism. If no, then how does it work? what happens if I redeploy the war file with updates to entity ABCD with few properties added/removed?

A concrete example that shows how hazelcast can be used that leverages user code deployment/distributed classloading/entry processors/map listenrs - things that can especially run on cache server node?

Need to understand what do I need to really put on war 1 which is client and war 2 that goes to cache server.

Answer (score 1):

@kalpesh-soni, if you use the BINARY in memory format, and only use simple map put/get operations, there is no need to deploy the class to the hazelcast member. Since format is BINARY, it’ll be stored as a byte array. When you change your class on the client side, old entries won’t have those new properties. You can handle it by adding a version field & serialize/deserialize based on the version.

Comment: what are other formats, and if i dont use binary format, what is the deployment mechanism, also why should i use non-binary?

Comment: For open source, BINARY and OBJECT, and there's NATIVE format is you use Enterprise edition: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Setting_In_Memory_Format.html

Comment: you can use User code deployment to deploy new/updated classes (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Setting_Up_Clusters/Client_User_Code_Deployment_-_BETA.html) but you need to take care of the versioning on your own or need to use a serialization that solve that problem.

Comment: Hazelcast has `VersionedPortable` serisalization for that, some 3rd party serisaliation tools can alos handle this.

Comment: `OBJECT` format is good if you're using Predicate queries on non-indexed fields or using EntryProcessors heavily. But with the penalty of extra serialization/deserialization each time you do put/get

Comment: `NATIVE` is same with `BINARY`, the difference is data stored off-heap

Comment: thanks a lot, entry processor and map listener is certainly fancy, do I have an option of running some of those in cache server memory? also any concrete example for user code deployment and distributed classloading?

Comment: Entry processors,  by design, run on the cluster, not on the caller. You can check sample repo for examples: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples. EP example is under `distributed-map` and user code deployment is under `clients`